# How do I hide my followers on my Spotify profile?

Tags: spotify

Users who visit my profile on Spotify can see who I follow and who my followers are. How do I hide this information so that it is not public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to hide your followers or who you follow from other Spotify users.